# Sorting alphanumeric array with java-script

Tags: javascript, arrays, natsort

I have a alphanumeric array -

```
var a1 =["3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP", "3500", "stack-TA", "2620-48-PoEP", "2120", "3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP"];
```

I tried sorting this array using natsort which gives me the correct output -

```
`Array ( [4] => 2120 [3] => 2620-48-PoEP [1] => 3500 [0] => 3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP [5] => 3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP [2] => stack-TA )`
```

I tried doing the same with `javascript` -

```
var a1 =["3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP", "3500", "stack-TA", "2620-48-PoEP", "2120", "3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP"];

    var a2 = a1.sort(function(a,b){
        var charPart = [a.substring(0,1), b.substring(0,1)],
            numPart = [a.substring(1)*1, b.substring(1)*1];

        if(charPart[0] < charPart[1]) return -1;
        else if(charPart[0] > charPart[1]) return 1;
        else{ //(charPart[0] == charPart[1]){
            if(numPart[0] < numPart[1]) return -1;
            else if(numPart[0] > numPart[1]) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
    });
    $('#r').html(a2.toString())
```

which gives me the output - 
`2620-48-PoEP,2120,3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP,3500,3800tl-24G-2XG-PoEP,stack-TA`.

Why the javascript code is not taking 2120 as the 1st element.
What is wrong with the javascript code ?

Comment: It'll not help you to resolve your problem, but when you try to get a char would be easier to use brackets `[]`, instead of `substring()`, e.g.: `var charPart = [a[0], b[0]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line...

```
[a.substring(1)*1, b.substring(1)*1]
```

... with ...

```
[parseInt(a.substring(1), 10), parseInt(b.substring(1), 10)]
```

... and it will work ([**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwCr6/)), though the sorting function still won't be as universal as possible.

Explanation: `a.substr(1)*1` (better written as just `+a.substr(1)`, btw) casts that substring into `Number` type. In theory, that should give you a real number. In JS practice, however, it'll fail (giving `NaN`) if the rest of the string is not a complete representation of a number, having nothing except but that number.

For example, for  `2620-48-PoEP` line, `'620-48-PoEP'` is cast to `Number`. Now JS cannot interpret it as `620` - it'll be too bold for it, as there are some other meaningful (=non-whitespace) characters there. So instead of giving you `620`, it gives you `NaN`.

Now, any comparison between `NaN` and `NaN` is false (expect `!=`) - and that'll essentially make your sorting function gone haywire.

---

As a sidenote, `array.sort` updates the object in-place - you don't need to use another reference to it (`a2` variable), you can work with `a1`.

Comment: after replacing its not returning anything

Comment: @user3496418 Check the demo (console output).

Comment: can you see the output ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you mean. After `a1.sort`, you'll end up with that array sorted, so you can do whatever you want with it. For example, show in HTML with `$('#r').html(a1.join('<br>'));`, like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLM5d/).

Comment: Yea I understood that. thank you for such a detailed explanation.